# I need my work checked(properties of operations)

Tags: binary-operations

Let $x * y = |x + y|.$

$x * y = |x + y| = |y + x| = y * x,$ so $*$ is commutative.

$(x * y) * z = ||x + y| + z| = |x + |x + z|| =  x * (y * z),$ so $*$ associative.

$x * e = |x + e| = x,$ so $e = 0.$ Further, $e * x = |0 + x| = x.$ So, $*$ has an identity.

$x * x' = |x + x'| = e,$ so $x' = e - x.$ Further, $x' * x = |e - x + x| = e.$ So, every element has an inverse.

---

Let $x * y = |xy|.$

$x * y = |xy| = |yx| = y* x,$ so $*$ commutative.

$(x * y) * z = |(xy)z| = |x(yz)| = x * (y * z),$ so $*$ associative.

$x * e = |xe| = x,$ so, $e = 1$. Further, $e * x = |1x| = x$. So, $*$ has no identity.

$x * x' = |xx'| = e, $ so $x' = \frac ex$. Further, $x' * x = |\frac ex x| = e$. So, every element has an inverse.

---

Let $x * y = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}.$

$x * y = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = \sqrt{y^2 + x^2} = y*x$, so $*$ is commutative.

$(x * y) * z = \sqrt{(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})^2 + z^2} = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} = \sqrt{x^2 + (\sqrt{y^2 + z^2})^2} = x * (y * z),$ so $*$ is associative.

$x * e = \sqrt{x^2 + e^2} = x,$ so $e = 0.$ Further, $e * x = \sqrt{0 + x^2} = x.$ So, $*$ has an identity.

$x * x' = \sqrt{x^2 + x'^2} = e,$ so $x' = \sqrt{e^2 - x^2} \text { and } x' = -\sqrt{e^2 - x^2}$. Further, $x' * x = \sqrt{(\sqrt{e^2 - x^2})^2 + x^2} = e.$ So, every element has an inverse.

---

Let $x * y = x - y.$

$x * y = x - y \neq y - x,$ so $*$ is not commutative.

$(x * y) * z = ((x - y) - z) = (x - (y - z),$ so $*$ is not associative.

$x * e = x - e = x,$ so $e = 0$. Further, $e * x = 0 - x = -x.$ So, $*$ has no identity.

$x * x' = x - x' = e,$ so $x' = x - e$. Further, $x' * x = x - e - x = -e.$ So, not every element has an inverse.

---

Let $x * y = xy + 1.$

$(x * y) * z = xy+ 1  = 1 + xy,$ so $*$ is commutative.

$(x * y) * z = (xyz + z) + 1  = xyz + (z + 1),$ so $*$ is associative.

$x * e = xe + 1 = x, $ so $e = 0$. Further, $e * x = 0x + 1 = 1.$ So, $*$ has no identity.

$x * x' = xx' + 1 = e,$ so $x' = \frac {e - 1}{x}.$ Further, $x' * x = \frac {e - 1}{x} x  + 1 = e$, so every element has an inverse.

---

Let $x * y = max\{x, y\}.$

$(x * y) * z = max\{max\{x, y\}, z\} = max\{max \text { } x, \{y , z\}\},$ so $*$ is associative.

$x * e = max\{x, e\} = x,$ so $e = min\{x, e\}.$ Futher, $e * x = max\{min\{x, e\}, x\} = x,$ so $*$ has an identity.

$x * x' = max\{x, x'\} \neq e,$ so $x'$ is undefined. Not every element has an inverse.

Comment: The absolute value one isn't commutative. $|-30+|10+10|| = |-30+20| = |10| = 10$, but $||-30+10|+10| = ||-20|+10| = |20+10| = 30.$

Comment: Thanks. Do the rest look ok?

Comment: $x∗y=xy+1$ associativity in this part is also wrong. From way you have written proof it does not really seem like you have complete understanding of what you are doing. (and I guess that's why you are asking) Make sure you REALLY understand what commutative, associative, existence of identity and inverse means. 

Also you should specify the domain as well?!

Comment: @ZachEffman I think you mean associative instead of commutative

Comment: @ Jack Yoon, is $(x * y) * z = (xy + 1)z + 1,$ correct? The problems are given that way, no domains specified.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt Thanks, yes I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List of mistakes and potential improvements:

Problem 1) The associativity proof is not correct, and you can use a counterexample to prove it - say $||1+1|-2|=0$, but $|1+|1-2||=2$.

Problem 2) In the associativity proof, to be technically correct, it should read $||xy|z|=|x|yz||$ instead of just having parentheses for the inside pairings. The no identity part of this could also use cleaning up: you should state more clearly why no identity exists - say be considering $x=-1$ and noting that whatever the other element $x*y\ge0>x$

Problem 3) You should check here that an inverse actually exists - you have an expression here, but you know $e=0$. When you try and find the inverse of $1$, you may have some problems with taking the square root of a negative number.

Problem 4) There should be a $\ne$ sign in your associativity proof, but your conclusion is correct.

Problem 5) There is a $z$ in commutivity case when there shouldn't be - I think this was just a typo. The associativity case is wrong: $(x*y)*z=xyz+z+1$, but $x*(y*z)=xyz+x+1$. I don't see how you concluded $e=0$ - solving for $e$ gets you $e=\frac{x-1}{x}$ which has problems in that it is dependent on $x$ - so no identity exists. Since no identity exists, it's impossible for inverses to exist.

Problem 6) The identity needs to work for an arbitrary element hence you need $e=-\infty$. A short statement of commutivity should also be included in this part.

Comment: Can we say $x'$ in (3) is undefined and therefore no inverse exists? Can you elaborate a bit more on associativity in (5) and $e$ in (6)? Thanks.

Comment: @AbstraktAlgebra Well, it's defined for $0$, but it's not defined for anything else (assuming you are not allowing complex numbers), but basically, yes you can just say that an inverse if it existed would be complex, so inverses don't exist in general. 

For the associativity in $5$, we have $(x*y)*z=(xy+1)*z=xyz+z+1$. Similarly $x*(y*z)=x*(yz+1)=xyz+x+1$. These in general aren't equal - we can take say $x=1$, $y=0$, $z=0$ for a concrete example.

Now for $e$ in $6$. We need $\max\{x,e\}=x$ for every $x$. Hence $e$ must be less than or equal to every $x$. Hence $e$ must be $-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

For number 5: 
it is not associate. 
you did not check:
$(x∗y)∗z=x∗(y∗z)$

Also, you said "$xe+1=x$, so $e=0$" well if $e=0$ then we get $1=x$ but we need $x=x$ either way, you are right there is no identity but you did not provide the right reason.

This is important: If there is no identity then there is no inverse. So you contradicted yourself in the inverse part.

Hopefully this helps!